# CacheManager GetData performance issue

Tags: enterprise-library

We are using Enterprise Library 5 and the CacheManager that it provides in our web application. Everything seems to be working fine up to the point where we start a heavy load test on the application.

We are caching records from the database using a key based on their ID. We are not requesting from cache one item all the time, sometimes we need to get a list of items from the cache. For this we have a LINQ query that makes a Select(e => CacheManager.GetData(id_from_list)) and returns the list of items from the cache. Most of the time this works fine but in heavy loads the GetData method becomes a bottleneck due to the locking that the cache manager is performing both on read and write operations from cache. Basically only one thread can read data from the cache at one time. We did create several cache managers based on the type of the items - this allows several threads to get data from different cache managers but still the issue remains when heavy loads hit the application (one bottleneck per cache manager) - of course it did improve the application up to some point but not enough.

Did someone else encountered the same problem and did you find a way to overcome this?

**NOTE:** We tried to actually cache lists of items and compose the key from the ids of the items in the list. This actually solved the problem and the cachemanager.getdata is not a bottleneck anymore ... BUT ... obviously this is not a good solution as we could have each item thousands of times in the cache in a lot of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider adapting the CacheManager to use a read/write lock (which I think is much more suitable for this situation) instead of the exclusive locking that it uses now.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx

Basically, a read/write lock is appropriate when multiple reader threads need simultaneous access to the data, and only the occurrence of a write will cause incoming readers to block.

These have other problems when put under load, however, such as write starvation. Depending on the read/write lock implementation a write will always wait for all reads to finish first - with a constant stream of reads a write will never have a chance to happen.

Comment: We actually created a custom implementation of the ICacheManager that does not do exclusive locking when reading. This improved a lot the performance of the web application.